# How to rename a column in ABP for .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, rename, entity-framework-migrations, aspnetboilerplate

How do I rename an entity property in the database in ABP for .NET Core template?

In ABP for .NET Framework, both the `ColumnAttribute` and Fluent API worked well.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add a new migration

```
public override void Up()
{          
    RenameColumn("dbo.Table", "ColumnName1", "ColumnName2"); 
}
```

Comment: thanks,Alper Ebicoglu. I made a mistake to add complex property including itself. after added [NotMapped]  attribute,it works well.

Comment: ohh ok. have fun with abp.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just rename the column name in model class.
2. Run Add-Migration  in Package Manager Console.(It will automatically add the necessary migration)
3. Run Update-Database in Package Manager Console.